# Force FireFox to render like Chrome?

Tags: html

Is there a attribute or tag that will force FF to render like chrome without a plugin? Or to maybe force it to another FF version like how IE you can `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />`

Comment: Wow, if we had these options the browser compatibility issue would vanish!

Answer (score 6):

No, that isn't possible. Firefox isn't an old version of Chrome or anything - it's a different browser with a different rendering engine.

It's sort of like asking if you can force Internet Explorer 3 to render like Mobile Safari. Not happening.

Comment: `X-UA-Compatible` exists due to IE internal mess :) [relevant link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)